# SVG images blink when their order is updating in Chrome

Tags: image, google-chrome, svg

I have a weird problem. I have a script that loads images into the SVG, and then user can manually update they order by clicking on them: the clicked image goes up in the SVG tree.

The problem is that in Chrome all images blink when their order in the tree is changing. However, Firefox and Safari work with no blinking. Moreover, I have a copy of this script on the other domain and it doesn't blink there too.

Is it possible that the blinking is caused by some domain-related issue? In both cases images are on the same domain as the page. I use Chrome 18.

Comment: Can you put this on jsfiddle or otherwise supply a link to an example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can call `suspendRedraw()` method on any element in SVG when you need to make complex manipulations or when you encounter bugs like you are describing. And when you're done with manipulations call `unsuspendRedraw()` on the same element to let browser rerender the image. I would call the methods on the parent element of your images.